# Deploying Firebase Functions onWrite realtime with two different databases

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've two apps, same logic, but differents database.

On app 1, I use database-1, for app 2, I use database-2.

On my first app, I've deployed a onWrite functions, that's works well. The function is trigged and everything works well.

Now I want to deploy the same function, on the same project but with different database, it's that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
functions.database.instance('database-2').ref('/foo/bar')
```

According to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path), you can specify a Realtime Database instance with `instance('INSTANCE_NAME')`.